# C and SDL in Ubuntu not working as intended

Tags: c, ubuntu, sdl, sdl-2

I am following a tutorial on Youtube, but it does not work as intended when I try it.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

void start(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello", 200, 200, 200, 200, 0);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    SDL_Rect rect = {220, 140, 200, 200};
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
}

void stop(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;

    start(window, renderer);
    SDL_Delay(5000);
    stop(window, renderer);

    return 0;
}
```

It is supposed to create a white rectangle in the middle of the window and fill the rest with blue color, but that does not happen when I run it. Instead, it "captures a picture" of the program under it, for example the background. Why is this happening, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Try adding `SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);` to update the screen.

Comment: Where should I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues to fix.  First, you need to modify your `start()` function to take pointers-to-pointers, rather than just pointers, so that the `window` and `renderer` variables in `main()` can be modified... otherwise, `window` and `renderer` within `start()` will be valid, but the corresponding pointer variables in `main()` will not be changed and will remain uninitialized.  So...

```
/* Use 'SDL_Window**' and 'SDL_Renderer**' instead of 'SDL_Window*' and
 *  'SDL_Renderer*', and dereference once during use (eg. '*window' 
 *  instead of 'window' */
void start(SDL_Window** window, SDL_Renderer** renderer)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello", 200, 200, 200, 200, 0);
    *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(*window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(*renderer, 0, 0, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(*renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(*renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    SDL_Rect rect = {220, 140, 200, 200};
    SDL_RenderFillRect(*renderer, &rect);
}
```

Then in `main()` use:

```
    start(&window, &renderer); /* pass addresses, not values */
```

The second issue is that you need to update the screen after finishing the drawing operations.  You can do this with `SDL_RenderPresent()` when you're
done drawing, such as in `main()` right after calling your `start()` function:

```
...
    start(&window, &renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); /* add this */
    SDL_Delay(5000);
...
```

You may also want to change the values in your `SDL_Rect` so that it's not drawn outside the window.

Comment: I'm a newbie, so don't go too hard on me. Shouldn't a pointer be passed by reference, which means that it's value can be changed from another function? Why do I have to use a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: @ErikW Passing a pointer lets you modify the thing it points at.. but in this case, since the thing you want to modify *is* a pointer, you need a *pointer to a pointer*.